# angular2 .net core app adding css and js libraries

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

After I created the application as you know there is a default vender css library referenced in layout so I added css files of my template in same directory(wwroot/assets )with the same syntax but its not work but there is no error about the ref(not found) so it suppose to be loaded to browser but its not..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/vendor.css" asp-append-version="true" />

<!-- Custom files-->
        <link class="nor-css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/assets/css/global/bootstrap.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/assets/css/switchery/switchery.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/assets/css/global/slidePanel.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/assets/css/global/waves.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/assets/plugin/bootstrap-tour/css/bootstrap-tour.css" asp-append-version="true" />
```

How can I import these css files to project? How Angular2 .core file system works about it?

here is the template from my mvc app, I coped the references and libraries all definetely same.
here is the pages original and my development sample
[image]

Comment: This should work. Working for me. Did you find any issue there?